# What code can be written in order to sort expiry date?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
#         type                                  mass   Expiry date
10-107  Drain Deck  √           9kg Jan-20
3033    Drain Deck  √           25kg    Jan-20
4033    Cellar Deck     √       5kg Jan-20
4035    Cellar Deck     √       5kg Jan-20
4023    Cellar D        √       5kg Jan-20
1095    Cellar Deck √           9kg Jan-20
10-111  Cellar Deck √           9kg Jan-20
1008    Cellar Deck √           9kg Jan-20
```

I am now creating a table that shows the nearest expiry date for a group of items. Before when the dates were different I didn't face any problem because i was using Min formula, But now when the date are the same i can not use min formula anymore.
What I think would work the best is to create a Macro that would check if the dates are the same then just copy the date to a certain cell ,and if the dates are different it will just copy the date which is the nearest to be expired. Any suggestions?
Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Look into pivot tables, which are a good way to poke around, sort, and aggregate your data with minimal startup time.

Comment: Since the ultimate aim is to sort.. Does [ selectAll > Data > Filter : set ascending / descending ] work for your need?